# Comprehension issue: Precompiled headers & include usage

Tags: c++, include, precompiled-headers

I got a comprehension issue about precompiled headers, and the usage of the #include directive.
So I got my "stdafx.h" here and include there for example vector, iostream and string. The associated "stdafx.cpp" only includes the "stdafx.h", that's clear.

So if I design my own header file that uses for example "code" that's in vector or iostream, I have to include the header file because the compiler doesn't know the declarations at that time. So why are some posts here ([include stdafx.h in header or source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234311/include-stdafx-h-in-header-or-source-file)) saying, it's not good to include the "stdafx.h" in other header files even if this file includes the needed declarations of e.g. vectors? So basically it wouldn't matter to include directly a vector or the precompiled header file, both do the same thing.

I know of course, that I don't have to include a header file in another header file if the associated source file includes the needed header file, because the declarations are known at that time. Well, that only works if the header file is included somewhere.

So my question is: Should I avoid including the precompiled header file in any source file and why? And I am a bit confused, because I'm reading contradictory expressions on the web that I shouldn't include anything in header files anyway, or is it O.K. to include in header files?
So what's right now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be a bit of a blanket statement with intent. The typical setup for PCH in a Visual Studio project [follows this general design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535050/c-precompiled-header-defined-in-a-header-vs2010-compiler-cant-find/12535543#12535543), and is worth reviewing. That said:

1. Design your header files as if there is no PCH master-header.
2. Never build include-order dependencies in your headers that you expect the including source files will fulfill prior to your headers.
3. The PCH master-header notwithstanding (I'll get to that in a moment), always include your custom headers *before* standard headers in your source files. This makes your custom header is more likely to be properly defined and not reliant on the including source file's previous inclusion of some standard header file.
4. Always set up appropriate include guards or pragmas to avoid multiple inclusion. They're critical for this to work correctly.

The PCH master-header is not to be included in your header files. When designing your headers, do so with the intent that everything needed (and *only* that which is needed) by the *header* to compile is included. If an including source file needs additional includes for its implementation, it can pull them in as needed after your header.

The following is an example of how I would setup a project that uses multiple standard headers in both the .h and .cpp files.

**myobject.h**

```
#ifndef MYAPP_MYOBJECT_H
#define MYAPP_MYOBJECT_H

// we're using std::map and std::string here, so..
#include <map>
#include <string>

class MyObject
{
    // some code

private:
    std::map<std::string, unsigned int> mymap;
};

#endif
```

Note the above header should compile in whatever .cpp it is included, *with or without PCH being used*. On to the source file...

**myobject.cpp**

```
// apart from myobject.h, we also need some other standard stuff...

#include "myobject.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

// code, etc...
```

Note `myobject.h` does not expect you to include something it relies on. It isn't using `<iostream>` or `<algorithm>`, etc. in the header; we're using it here.

That is a typical setup with no PCH. Now we add the PCH master

---

**Adding the PCH Master Header**

So how do we set up the PCH master-header to turbo-charge this thing? For the sake of this answer, I'm only dealing with pulling in standard headers and 3rd-party library headers that will not undergo change with the project development. You're not going to be editing `<map>` or `<iostream>` (and if you are, get your head examined).  Anyway...

1. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535050/c-precompiled-header-defined-in-a-header-vs2010-compiler-cant-find/12535543#12535543) for how a PCH is typically configured in Visual Studio. It shows how one file (usually `stdafx.cpp`) is responsible for generating the PCH, the rest of your source files then use said-PCH by including `stdafx.h`.
2. Decide what goes in the PCH. As a general rule, that is how your PCH should be configured. Put non-volatile stuff in there, and leave the rest for the regular source includes. We're using a number of system headers, and those are going to be our choices for our PCH master.
3. Ensure each source file participating in the PCH turbo-mode is including the PCH master-header *first*, as described in the linked answer from (1).

So, first, the PCH master header:

**stdafx.h**

```
#ifndef MYAPP_STDAFX_H
#define MYAPP_STDAFX_H

// MS has other stuff here. keep what is needed

#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

#endif
```

Finally, the source files configured to use this then do this. The *minimal* change needed is:

**UPDATED: myobject.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h" // <=== only addition
#include "myobject.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

// code, etc...
```

Note I said *minimal*. In reality, none of those standard headers need appear in the .cpp anymore, as the PCH master is pulling them in. In other words, you *can* do this:

**UPDATED: myobject.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "myobject.h"

// code, etc...
```

Whether you choose to or not is up to you. I prefer to keep them. Yes, it *can* lengthen the preprocessor phase for the source file as it pulls in the headers, runs into the include-guards, and throws everything away until the final `#endif`. If your platform supports `#pragma once` (and VS does) that becomes a near no-op.

But make no mistake: The most important part of all of this is the header `myobject.h` was not changed *at all*, and does *not* include, or know about, the PCH master header. It shouldn't have to, and should not be built so it has to.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Everything's now perfectly clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

When using the precompiled header feature, every .cpp file must begin by including the stdafx.h header. If it does not, a compiler error results. So there is no point in putting the include in some header file. That header file cannot be included unless the stdafx.h has already been included first.

Comment: So your answer is, that I dont have to include anything in my designed header file, because I include in the .cpp file stdadx.h before the actual header file ? Well, that only works if I have an associated source  file, the header file could implement all things inline.

Comment: The header file has to be #included in some source file or it will not be compiled at all.

Comment: Yea i'm aware of that, so you give me the advise to place no #include directives in my header files, because when I'm including it in a source file i should include the needed headers there ?

Comment: @YannikK. Absolutely not. Do *not* build source-file include-order dependencies in your compilation unit. Your headers should *never* assume the included source file will include the "right stuff" prior pulling in your header. if your header has dependency on some other header, your header includes it *in the header*, period.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, that's a clear answer. Just another question thats about the "precompiled header" part of the general question: Why shouldn't I include "stdafx.h" in my header files, even if it includes the headers I need in that header file ?

Comment: @YannikK. that question is worthy of a ton more than I can show in a comment here. It will be a bit before I have something.

Comment: @WhozCraig I appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Precompiled headers are a method to shorten the build time.  The idea is that the compiler could "precompile" declarations and definitions in the header and not have to parse them again.

With the speed of todays computers, the precompilation is only significant for huge projects.  These are projects with a minimum of over 50k lines of code.  The definition of "signification" is usually tens of minutes to build.

There are many issues surrounding Microsoft's `stdafx.h`. In my experience, the effort and time spent with discovering and resolving the issues, makes this feature more of a hassle for smaller project sizes. I have my build set up so most of the time, I am compiling only a few files; the files that don't change are not compiled.  Thus, I don't see any huge impact or benefit to the precompiled header.

Comment: Well that's a nice statement, but doesn't answer my question. My question is not just about precompiled headers and problems with using them. I am just asking when should I include in my header files e.g. something like <vector>, when the associated .cpp includes vector anyway, so i dont have to include it in the header file. But here is the problem this "way" only works when I have an associated source file, if not, e.g. all is implemented in the header (inline) I HAVE TO include the header files in my header.